# 接着した2つのURLを正規表現で分離し、ソートしたい

Tags: linux, 正規表現, bash

現在、任意のサイトのディレクトリトラバーサルの脆弱性をチェックするシェルスクリプトを書いています。しかしこのシェルスクリプトには一つ問題があり、`出力結果のURLが1つの文字列と合体して出力`されてしまいます。

まず、コードと出力結果を貼っておきます。

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sleeptime=6 

function test_run() 
{
        echo "[+] Starting Test..."
        result="";
        for start in $(seq 1 35); 
            do
                query=$(echo; curl -sS "https://serx.ml/search?q=$site%20$1&categories=general&time_range=None&safesearch=0&pageno=$start")
                checkdata=$(echo "$query" | grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_~-]*$1/[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_~-]*")
                if [ -z "$checkdata" ]
                    then
                        sleep $sleeptime; 
                        break; 
                    else
                        result+=$checkdata;
                        sleep $sleeptime; 
                fi
            done


        if [ -z "$result" ] 
            then
                echo "[-] No results"
            else
                IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort -u <<<"${result[@]}"| tr " " "\n"));
                echo -e " " 
                for each in "${sorted[@]}"; do echo "     [+] $each"; done
        fi
}
test_run xxx.yyy.co.jp
```

(出力結果)

```
[+] Starting Test...
 
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/?ND
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/?SA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/Data/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/Date/?ND
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/Digest/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/Digest/Perl/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/HTML/?MD
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/Mail/?DA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/Mail/?DAhttp://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/Digest/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/PDFJ/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/PDFJ/?MA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/PDFJ/?MD
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/PDFJ/?ND
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/PDFJ/?NDhttp://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/PDFJ/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/PDFJ/?SA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/SQL/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/SQL/Dialects/?MD
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/SQL/Dialects/?MDhttp://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/SQL/Dialects/?NA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/SQL/Dialects/?NA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/SQL/Dialects/?SD
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/SQL/Statement/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/ilchianti_kawagoe/mod/XML/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/?DA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/?MD
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/?SA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/?SD
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/Data/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/Date/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/Date/?SA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/Digest/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/Digest/Perl/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/Digest/Perl/http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/?SA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/HTML/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/Mail/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/PDFJ/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/PDFJ/?MA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/PDFJ/?MD
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/PDFJ/?SA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/PDFJ/?SD
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/SQL/?MA
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/SQL/Dialects/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/SQL/Dialects/?MD
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/SQL/Statement/
     [+] http://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/XML/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/?MD
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/?MA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/?SA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/?SAhttp://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/?MD
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/?SD
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/?ND
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/?MA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/?DD
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/?MA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/?ND
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/?SA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/?SD
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/?SDhttp://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/?SA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/?SA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/?SD
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2016/?MA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2017/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/?NA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/?SA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/?DA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/?SA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/?ND
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/?ND
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/?MA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/?SA
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2019/?MD
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/?MD
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/?MDhttp://xxx.yyy.co.jp/mod/XML/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/?MD
     [+] http://www.xxx.yyy.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/?ND
```

このように部分的に1つの文字列に2つURLがドッキングする形で出力されてしまいます。この問題をなんとか正規表現で解決したいのですが、現在に至るまでうまく解決できていません。

現在わかっていることは、`result+=$checkdata;`という複合代入を行うとURLが重なる現象が起こるようです。しかし解決策はわかっていない状態です。

この場合どのような方法を使えば出力結果をソートできるのでしょうか？
ご指摘は常に返信でお返しいたします。

Comment: curlを実行したときのqueryの内容で、URLは1行ずつ分離されていますか？この段階でドッキングしていますか？

Comment: queryはcurlでスクレイピングした`生のhtmlファイル`が格納されています。その生ソースから正規表現で目的のURLをクロールしていきます。なのでURLは分離されていません。こちらがqueryの中身です。是非参考になさってください。https://0bin.net/paste/DbBdmm6-#5OmDuPF2sTB8fY4NEDjOPftSwdrPgH144tc7pvr6hVU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのまま試せるようなコードでは無いので確認していませんが…… 恐らく下記が原因でしょう。

#### コマンド置換での末尾改行の削除

これは `bash` に限りませんが、コマンド置換では末尾の改行文字が削除されます。

> `$(command)`
> ...
> bash は command を実行し、 command の標準出力でコマンド置換の部分を置き換えます。 この際、**末尾の改行文字は削除されます**。
> —— [Man page of BASH](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html)

よって、変数に `+=` する前か後に改行も足せばよいはずです。

（ただ、そもそもの話になりますが、こうやって変数に蓄積していくのでは無く、`curl | grep | sort` とパイプで繋げていく方が簡潔になると思います）

Comment: コマンド置き換えを使わずに改行を挿入することに苦戦しましたが、`grep -Eo "(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_~-]*`の応用でコマンド自体で改行させて解決しました。もしかすると自作関数もコマンドとして認識されたかもしれません。とはいえコマンド呼び出しをワンライナーで呼び出して処理したほうが確かに簡素ですし、今後のメンテに貢献してくれると思います。今後実装してみます。貴重な回答により解決に導いてくださり、ありがとうございます。